# LG P500 unplugged during update, now it wont go past telus screen!

Tags: lg-optimus-one

I was updating my LG P500 2.2.1. While it was updating, my phone was in emergency mode and it got unplugged. Now when I turn it on it goes to the android screen, then gets stuck on the telus screen! I called lg and they told me to do a factory reset by holding the home, power and volume down keys. This did NOT work, it still will not go past the telus screen.. PLZ tell me there is a way to make it work again..

Comment: Turned off press. Pressing the home+power+volDown keys for a long time. Wait until a menu appears. Did the list of menu appear?

Comment: no it just had the android guy and a box, showing the factory reset

Comment: @geffchange even after i did the reset it still wont go past the telus screen

Comment: How long does it stay at the telus screen?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you have fixed this or not.

If you are still out of luck, try root the phone via below tutorial:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1832485

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's great to have you here, but answers that are essentially just a link [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). It would be great if you [edit]ed your question and fleshed it out so that it stands on its own without the link.

Comment: As @dotVezz wrote, link-only answers are discouraged: in case the link dies, they become useless. Please, at least include *an extract* of the essential information from behind it, and keep the link *for reference*. Thanks a lot!